# Multiple IFS to check for three different values in on cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have 3 sheets S1, S2, and S3 that I use on a 4th sheet that I use formulas to index and match IP addresses. S1 contains a mapping of NAT IPs for the client's A private subnet and S2contains a mapping of NAT IPs for the client's B private subnet i.e. (A) 10.1.1.1 (B2) 100.

I use S4 A2 - AX and input an IP that I want to look i.e 100.100.1.1, B2 will Index and match S3 and return the IP in question which tells me it exists in the database. then in C2, I want to use the value in B2 and index and match the proper sheet based on the 1st & 2nd octet of the IP... i.e if the 1st two octets start with 100.100.x.x then index and match S1 if the IP starts with 100.200. then look it up on S2 and if the IP starts with 10.x.x.x I want to look it up on the sheets and return its mapped NAT IP if it exists.
=IFS(LEFT(A2,8)="100.100.",INDEX('S1.csv'!$C:$C,MATCH(B2,'S1.csv'!$F:$F,0)),LEFT(A2,8)="100.200.",INDEX('S2.csv'!$C:$C,MATCH(B2,'S2.csv'!$F:$F,0)))

I am stuck on how to do these check those three conditions :( I tried IFS, IFERROR, OR, AND but still not able to figure it out. any help suggestions are highly appreciated.

what I am trying to accomplish here is:
check if cellA2 contains an IP of 100.100.x.x, if true lookup its nat address. if the IP starts with 100.200 return its real IP from the client's B sheet and if it is not 100.100.x.x nor 100.200.x.x and it starts with 10. or 65 etc.. return its NAT'd IP.

thank you in advance

Comment: Could you share the current setup and the desired result?

Comment: @JanWillem, imagine that column Ax - Axxxx contains IP addresses. I want to have a formula on Bx - Bxxxx that will take the IP from the corresponding A cell and if that IP starts with 100.100.x.x do this, if the IP starts with 100.200.x.x do that else if the IP starts with 10 do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should nest the if statements for each case. Another tip: you could use the LET function to capture the LEFT 7 characters of the IP address and store it in a variable (in my case called domain):

```
=LET(domain,LEFT(A2,7),IF(domain="100.100",[do the index/match in S1],IF(domain="100.200",[do the index/match in S2],[do the index/match in S3])))
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you for this, I learned something new about the Let(). can you let me know why the OR() is not working here:`code`=LET(domain,LEFT(A2,7),IF(domain="100.100",INDEX('S1.csv'!$C:$C,MATCH(B2,'S1.csv'!$F:$F,0)),IF(domain="100.200",INDEX('S2.csv'!$C:$C,MATCH(B2,'S2.csv'!$F:$F,0))),OR(INDEX('S2.csv'!$F:$F,MATCH(B4,'S2.csv'!$C:$C,0)),INDEX('S2.csv'!$F:$F,MATCH(B4,'S1.csv'!$C:$C,0)))))`code`

Comment: OR() returns a TRUE or FALSE if at least one of the statements in it returns true: So for example OR(1=1,1=0) returns TRUE, OR(0=1, 1=2) returns FALSE. It looks like you are trying to use it like it was an ELSE statement, which is not how it works